# Can TimePicker be used without header on Android

Tags: android, timepicker

I am using the `<TimePicker>` widget to enable the user to set the time. 
However, since I'm embedding the `<TimePicker>` into one of my views, I'd like to get rid of the `TimePicker`'s header (the crossed out area in the picture).

Default timepicker in Android looks like this:

**Question:** Is it possible to remove the timepicker's header and use only the analog part of the widget?

[image: AndroidPicker]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no public method in `TimePicker` to directly hide or show the Time Header. Try the below source code will give us the name of the resource ID for that View, which we can get with the system Resources. Then finding the View, and setting its visibility to `GONE`.(I haven't tested)

```
private void hideTimeHeaderLayout(TimePicker picker) {
    final int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("time_header", "id", "android");
    final View timeLayout = picker.findViewById(id);
    if(timeLayout != null) {
        timeLayout .setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```